# What is the criteria for a question to be "Not Constructive"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I've seen two questions lately that I thought might be candidates to be closed as "not constructive"; the [first](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/what-is-a-good-set-of-coding-conventions-for-salesforce-development) has been voted up quite a lot but the [second](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9838/triggers-should-contain-no-real-implementation-code-only-callouts-to-utility-m) was closed. In my opinion, both of them are rather open-ended and will likely solicit "extended discussion" so I'm wondering why only one of them was closed.

For the record, I voted up the first and didn't come across the second until it was already closed.

Answer (score 2):

the first should probably have been closed but I know I never saw any flags for it. The second was flagged by a user very quickly.

Although coding conventions do often start fights I think in this context the question is likely to elicit few good answers as opposed to discussion, but is a candidate for closure as there is no right answer.

the second question is considerably more open than the first as it is phrased to invite discussion, and pretty much establishes two 'sides' for people to stand on.